# Signature generation

Tags: raw-transaction, signature, message-signing

I am trying to unwrap bitcoin transaction generation process.

A bit confused about signing part.

My understanding is the transaction is sha256'd, then sha256'd one more time, then ECDSA'd.

Based off https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm, ECDSA will first hash the message. Does that mean the transaction is sha256'd **3** times in total?

All the best!

Johnny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only two hashes. The hash itself isn't typically described as a part of ECDSA though the input must already be hashed (because e.g. a signature of 0 is trivially forged).